# Eclipse plugin for file properties access within an editor?

Tags: eclipse

Is there an Eclipse plug-in that will allow me access to the properties of the file that I'm currently editing? I'd like it to be a part of the context (i.e. right-click menu) of the editor. I know this exists in the Navigator view, but having it in the context menu would be easier. I need it to set the read/write property of the file.

Comment: Would defining a keyboard shortcut work for you? You could quickly pull the file up in Explorer, then use a keyboard shortcut to navigate to Properties. 

http://www.eclipseonetips.com/2010/01/06/instantly-show-a-classfile-in-the-packageproject-explorer-in-eclipse/

I use AutoHotKey for problems like this and define my own custom shortcuts everywhere, but trying the built-in IDE options might be a more helpful place to start if you don't want to maintain your own simple automation scripts.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't use the Package Explorer (not as useful to me as Navigator) plus if I go to the Explorer, it's probably just as many clicks as going to the Navigator and doing the same thing.